# Working with ifstream, data within file being called does not print

Tags: c++, string, xcode9, ifstream

Here is my code, the goal is open a file, read the words within that file and keep a count of how many strings are within the file. My issue is that when I run my program and call the test file, only the first string of that file is read and printed, I'm not really sure what is going wrong with it, any help would be great.

here is what I have within my test file:

This &%file              should!!,...

have exactly 7 words.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream inputFile;
    string fileName, inputRead;
    string sentinel = "quit";
    int count = 0;

    cout<< "what file do you want to open?: ";
    cin>> fileName;

    inputFile.open(fileName);

    while(!inputFile){
        cout<< "\nError opening file." <<endl;

        cout<< "Please enter filename correctly: ";
        cin>> fileName;

        inputFile.open(fileName);

    }

    while(fileName != sentinel){
        if(inputFile){

            inputFile >> inputRead;

            count++;

            cout<< endl;
            cout<< fileName << " data" <<endl;
            cout<< "*********************************\n" <<endl;

            cout<< inputRead <<endl;

            cout<< "\n*********************************" <<endl;
            cout<< fileName << " has " << count << " words." <<endl;

            cout<< "\nEnter another file name or type \"quit\" to end: ";
            cin>> fileName;
        }
    }

    inputFile.close();

    cout<< endl;

}
```

Comment: When you say only the first string is printed, do you mean only the first word is printed before you are prompted for more input, or no more output is produced no matter how many times you enter a new file name?

Comment: no more output is produced no matter how many times I enter the file name, once i enter a file name, it prints the first string and then it prompts me again for a another file namel

Comment: You call `inputFile.open(fileName);` before the main loop. It succeeds exactly once. Why do you expect to be able to read from multiple files in the main loop? `cin>> fileName;` doesn't cause the file to be reopened.

Comment: ahhhh thanks, i just started learning C++, getting used to the logic of it and being able to follow the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the if statement inside the while loop. If the filename is not equal to sentinel, you check if inputFile is valid. If so you execute the lines of code inside just once before getting a new file name. What you want is something like this:

```
while(fileName != sentinel){
    cout<< endl;
    cout<< fileName << " data" <<endl;
    cout<< "*********************************\n" <<endl;
    while(inputFile >> inputRead){

        count++;


        cout<< inputRead <<endl;

    }
    cout<< "\n*********************************" <<endl;
    cout<< fileName << " has " << count << " words." <<endl;

    cout<< "\nEnter another file name or type \"quit\" to end: ";
    cin>> fileName;
}
```

Comment: Dont forget that the read operation may fail. You have to check that the read worked before you use it. The best way to do that is put the read as part of the while condition. Fixed the above code for you.